# plot bool-int scatter in different colors in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe as show below:

```
df =
       index           boolvalue  
2014-05-21 10:00:00            1        
2014-05-21 11:00:00            1        
2014-05-21 12:00:00            0      
2014-05-21 13:00:00            1        
2014-05-21 14:00:00            0        
2014-05-21 15:00:00            1 
....
```

The column just has two values, "1" and "0".

This are origin code and figure I have done:

```
plt.scatter(df.index, df.boolvalue, s = 5,c='b' )
plt.ylim([-2, 2])
```

[image]

l would like to plot it as a scatter plot, with value "1" in color **blue** and "0" in color **red** .

Because the index (time series) is long, I think it is better not to use a for-loop. Does anyone have an idea to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A scatter between what and what?

Comment: @AmiTavory I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider if you want a scatterplot or two boxplots.

For a scatterplot, you could use

```
for (v, c) in [(1, 'b'), (0, 'r')]:
    plt.scatter(df.index[df.boolvalue == v], df.boolvalue[df.boolvalue == v], s = 5,c=c)
```

Given the sample data, this looks like

[image]

For two boxplots, consider using [`seaborn.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(x="boolvalue", y="index", data=df.reset_index())
```